# iOS 5: ~/Library/Caches - How to check all required files are present a very smart way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file, ios5, storage

I guess everybody read about the recent issues with the new iOS 5.

e.g. at http://iPhoneIncubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5

My Magazine-App holds about 1k html/css/image/video files for every issue and I want to know if anything is missing.

So my question is how to check all required files are present a very smart way?

Comment: Apparently: iOS 5.0.1 beta is now available on the iOS Dev Center. It introduces a new way for developers to specify files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect iOS to clean caches atomically; i.e. iOS will either clean you app's cache or it will not.  It shouldn't partially remove files from your cache.  However, I don't believe this is documented behaviour, so it's a bad idea to assume this.

When you download your content, you have to know what to download for each issue, right?  So you already have some kind of manifest file that references every file that is needed by each magazine.  You should save this manifest locally so that you can refer to it when checking for the existence of files.  You can still save this in the caches directory, if it's missing, you know your cache has been at least partially cleaned.

Also, I don't believe there's any guarantee that iOS won't clean caches while your application is running.  As well as checking at the point where the user opens the magazine, you should check when your application becomes active after it has been put in the background, and your code should be robust in the face of missing files (i.e. pop up a warning message instead of crashing).

Answer (score 1):

You could zip all the files relating to each issue in an archive ([objective-c wrapper for zlib here](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/), to make life easier for you). That way you can make sure that the system either deletes your issue or not, without having to worry about individual files.

Comment: I did consider suggesting that for my answer, but the question indicates that there are a significant number of video files.  Zipping and unzipping those could potentially cause significant performance problems on both the client and server.  I've worked on an application that had to download large video files to be kept locally, and zipping wouldn't have been an option there.  It's certainly a good plan for smaller payloads though.